# Implementing push notification from iOS7 to iOS 11.* do i have to handle all three cases?

Tags: ios, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I know it will sound noobish but I have been used to integrating third-party SDK for APNs.

I have a legacy app which has to support iOS 7 and above, the application has push notification.
As per my understanding, we have a different approach to register for push notification for less thaniOS8, less thaniOS10 and different for iOS 10 and above.
so do I need to go with if condition checking for OS version like

```
   if(ios10 and above){
    // here register for iOS 10 and above

  }else if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
    // iOS 8 Notifications
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];

    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    // iOS < 8 Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
}
```

Is the above approach correct or I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

here is the snippet code I am using, for your reference :)

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
+ (void)registerAPNS {
  if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 10.0f) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                          }];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
  } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0f) {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
  } else {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert];
  }
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```